# Can't open a connection to create a transaction

Tags: ms-access, odbc

In MS-Access, I'm trying to get a connection so that I can run queries within a transaction.

Stripped down, the routine looks like this:

```
Public Sub SetConnection()
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    ConnectionString = CurrentDb.TableDefs("RandomTable").Connect
    If conn Is Nothing Then
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        PostToLog "SetConnection()", "Set Connection to " & ConnectionString
        conn.Open ConnectionString     '  Fails here
   '     conn.Open   '  Gives the same error without specifying the connection
    End If
    Exit Sub
```

I can see that the connection string is exactly that set in the Linked Table Manager.
Then I use it like this

```
Public Sub Begin()
    PostToLog "Begin()", "Start Begin"
    SetConnection
    If Not (conn Is Nothing) Then
        PostToLog "Begin()", "Begin"
        conn.BeginTrans
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Commit()
    PostToLog "Commit()", "Start Commit"
    If Not (conn Is Nothing) Then
        PostToLog "Commit()", "Committing"
        conn.CommitTrans
    End If
    CloseConnection
End Sub
Public Function GetConnection() As ADODB.Connection
' Use GetConnection() everywhere you want a connection. If in a transaction, these queries will automatically be included.
' The exception would be items that you do NOT want rolled back in case of failure, like logging.
    If conn Is Nothing Then
'        Set GetConnection = New ADODB.Connection
        Set GetConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
    Else
        Set GetConnection = conn
    End If
End Function
```

But the connection fails to open, conn isn't set, and everything happens outside a transaction.

The error is

```
Unspecified error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified: ConnectionString: ODBC;DSN=....
```

I've also tried

```
ConnectionString = CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
```

but that looked like the connection string to the front end Access database, not the back end.
I can't find any excuse for why the linked tables can find the DSN, but can't when I create the connection.

Begin, Commit, Rollback are used like so....

```
objSQL.Begin   ' Start transaction
' do some stuff that uses the conn connection
objSQL.Commit
Err: 
objSQL.Rollback
```

Update:
Using conn = CurrentProject.Connection instead of creating a new ADODB connection appears to work. No errors are thrown.
But the changes do not appear, as if they all get rolled back.
Postgres doesn't allow for a dirty read, so I can't tell if the changes never happened or if they do and get reversed. And if they do get reversed, I can't tell if that is before or after the Commit or what exactly triggers it. I *can* see the SQL statements appearing to get executed on the Postgres connection.

I'm going to try exploring a little more what happens when I have a proper connection string, as demonstrated by @HansUp

Comment: What happens if you do this instead of what you have now? `ConnectionString = Mid(CurrentDb.TableDefs("RandomTable").Connect, 6)`

Comment: I don't see conn declared. Is it already declared as global somewhere? `Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection` works for me in split db. However, my Transaction begin and commit are within one procedure. Why is there no rollback condition?

Comment: What database is your backend (MsAccess, SQLServer, ...)? Could they be linked DSNless?

Comment: @June7 Begin, Commit, and Rollback are all called from the same routines, with Rollback in the error handlers. Yes, conn is defined globally, as ADODB.Connection. I didn't bother to show Rollback, partially because it is the same as Commit, and partially because it doesn't call SetConnection, so isn't part of the problem I'm having.

Comment: @tinazmu  Backend is PostgreSQL. Probably could be DSNless.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by "Begin, Commit, Rollback are all called from the same routines". They are in different Sub's. Sorry, no experience with Transaction on non-Access backend.

Comment: If it is any help, I traced  SQL Server backend, which provided the linked tables to my MsAccess; and DAO workspace.BeginTrans, and Commit/Rollback cause MsAccess issue the correct begin, and commit/rollback instructions to SQL Server. Perhaps it could do so even when the backend is PostgreSQL? Could you use DAO (after all you are coding in MsAccess). If you can, you don;t need the underlying connection; you just need the CurrentDB (and Workspace) in MsAccess, and MsAccess will manage the rest.

Comment: I have also tried ADO connection from CurrentPRoject.Connection. and MsAccess issues the correct Begin Transaction and Commit instructions to the back-end SQL Server. So you should let MsAccess manage it, I would be surprised if it doesn't do it for PostgreSQL, as well.

Comment: @HansUp That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! But it turns out that my solution of getting a new connection causes other issues.

Comment: @June7 I added example usage.

Comment: added as reply; thanks

Comment: @tinazmu Reusing CurrentProject.Connection instead of creating a new connection solved my problem. Can you add this as an answer?  Well, I thought this worked until I looked closer at the posted data. The data is missing as if it got rolled back.

Comment: Maybe there is a situation related to connection pooling. Needs more investigation. I deleted my answer